# select input type next with not class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select all input type `texts` that don't have a particular class.

This is what I tried without success:

```
$('input.text:not(.fld-required-' + val + ')').each(function() {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

**UPDATE**
This is one input text I have that is not be selected:

```
<input placeholder="my_input" class="fld-required fld-required-1" name="my_input" type="text" required="">
```

Comment: Your code should work. If not, then we need to see the relevant HTML, along with where you define `val`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated the question

Comment: You don't have a `text` class inside the input, so your code won't execute since it includes onthe the inputs that have a text class.

Comment: I do not need to select input with "text" class, but of type "text"

Comment: Then you must use `input[type="text"]` instead of `input.text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a `text` class assigned to your input element.

You can use the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('input[type="text"]:not(.fld-required-' + val + ')').each(function() {
    $(this).val('');
});
```